# Function in R for several variables

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to unclass several factor variables in R. I need this functionality for a lot of variables. At the moment I repeat the code for each variable which is not convenient:

```
unclass:
  myd$ati_1 <-unclass(myd$ati_1) 
  myd$ati_2 <-unclass(myd$ati_2)  
  myd$ati_3 <-unclass(myd$ati_3) 
  myd$ati_4 <-unclass(myd$ati_4)
```

I've looked into the `apply()` function family but I do not even know if this is the correct approach. I also read about for loops but every example is only about simple integers, not when you need to loop over several variables.

Would be glad if someone could help me out.

Comment: `myd[1:4] <- lapply(myd[1:4], unclass)`

Comment: thanks, but these are not the first four variables, how can I access them?

Comment: So what's the pattern of variable names you want to unclass? Start with `"ati"`??

Comment: I had a survey with many items that people had to rate. In this case these four items belong to one construct. 
I have many more items with different names, but it would help if I could do multiple related items in one go

Comment: `lapply` can apply a function over multiple related items in one go. You have to tell us the logic to determine which variable names need to be `unclass`ed and which doesn't. E.g. unclass all variables whose names start with `"ati"`, or unclass all variables whose classes are factor.

Comment: It would be nice to unclass all variables whose classes are factor! Then I won't have to do it for all items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop:

```
    block <- c("ati_1", "ati_2", "ati_3", "ati_4")
    for (j in block) {myd[[j]] <- unclass(myd[[j]])}
# The double brackets allows you to specify actual names to extrapolate within the data frame
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ways.  We  use CO2 which comes with R and has several factor columns.  This unclasses those columns.

If you need some other criterion then

- set ix to the names or positions or a logical vector defining those columns to be transformed in the base R solution
- replace is.factor in the collapse solution with a vector of names or positions or a logical vector denoting the columns to convert
- in the dplyr solution replace where(...) with the same names, positions or logical.

Code follows.  In all of these the input is not overridden so you still have the input available unchanged if you want to rerun it from scratch and, in general, overwriting objects is error prone.

```
# Base R
ix <- sapply(CO2, is.factor)
replace(CO2, ix, lapply(CO2[ix], unclass))

# collapse
library(collapse)
ftransformv(CO2, is.factor, unclass)

# dplyr
library(dplyr)
CO2 %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.factor), unclass))
```

Depending on what you want this might be sufficient or omit the as.data.frame if a matrix result is ok.

```
as.data.frame(data.matrix(CO2))
```